# Замена числовых значений в datagridview на значения из массива без изменения основных данных

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Имеется datagrigview к которому через datasource привязывается list<> с данными
В list<> содержатся ид для подгрузки значений из других массивов
Нашел способ менять значения на нужные мне

```html
for (int i = 0; i < Championship.Members.Count; i++)
{
  DataGridViewTextBoxCell txtxCell = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5];
  string cellValue = txtxCell.Value.ToString();
  string trainer = Championship.Trainers[int.Parse(cellValue)].FullName.ToString();
  txtxCell.Value = trainer;
}
```

Но после изменения значение они автоматически записываются в list<>

Собственно, как отменить привязку данных после загрузки значений в datagridview или, может быть, есть более лаконичный способ заменить данные

Comment: Поставьте метку WPF или WinForms.

Comment: Благодарю, добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте событие [CellFormatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
private void DataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
    {
        e.Value = Championship.Trainers[int.Parse(e.Value.ToString())].FullName;
    }
}
```

Что-то в этом духе.